# JavaScript: Global variables after Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, global, synchronous

the question is fairly simple and technical:

```
var it_works = false;

$.post("some_file.php", '', function(data) {

     it_works = true;

});

alert(it_works); # false (yes, that 'alert' has to be here and not inside $.post itself)
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
alert(it_works); # true
```

Is there a way to do that? If not can `$.post()` return a value to be applied to `it_works`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-req

Answer (score 108, accepted):

What you expect is the **synchronous** (*blocking*) type request.

```
var it_works = false;

jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'some_file.php',
  success: function (data) {
    it_works = true;
  }, 
  async: false // <- this turns it into synchronous
});​

// Execution is BLOCKED until request finishes.

// it_works is available
alert(it_works);
```

Requests are **asynchronous** (*non-blocking*) by **default** which means that the browser won't wait for them to be completed in order to continue its work. That's why your alert got wrong result.

Now, with [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you can optionally set the request to be **synchronous**, which means that the script will only continue to run *after* the request is finished.

---

The **RECOMMENDED** way, however, is to **refactor** your code so that the data would be passed to a **callback** function as soon as the request is finished. This is preferred because blocking execution means blocking the UI which is unacceptable. Do it this way:

```
$.post("some_file.php", '', function(data) {
    iDependOnMyParameter(data);
});

function iDependOnMyParameter(param) {
    // You should do your work here that depends on the result of the request!
    alert(param)
}

// All code here should be INDEPENDENT of the result of your AJAX request
// ...
```

> **Asynchronous** programming is slightly more **complicated** because the consequence 
>   of making a request is encapsulated in a function instead of following the request statement. **But** the realtime behavior that the **user experiences** can be **significantly 
>   better** because they will not see a sluggish server or sluggish network cause the 
>   browser to act as though it had crashed. **Synchronous** programming is **disrespectful** 
>   and **should not be employed** in applications which are used by people.

*Douglas Crockford* ***([YUI Blog](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/04/synchronous-v-asynchronous/))***

Comment: But note that this will kill usability if `some_file.php` preforms a lot (expensive) operations.

Comment: @Felix Yes, but there are cases when synchronous I/O is essential. It's a tool that shouldn't be overused. Best to be avoided, one might say.

Comment: and **please note** that the question was `alert has to be here not inside. Is there a way to do that?`

Comment: @galambalazs I think your answer should mention the pitfalls of creating a synch xhr call

Comment: @galambalazs : Synchronous requests got deprecated, The standard know says using them will throw an error.

Comment: Chrome Console Message: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience."

Comment: Yeh .. great one async: false  .. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. Thus, the post to the server happens out-of-sync with the rest of the function. Try some code like this instead (it just breaks the shorthand `$.post` out into the longer `$.ajax` call and adds the `async` option).

```
var it_works = false;

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  url: "some_file.php",
  data: "",
  success: function() {it_works = true;}
});

alert(it_works);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

It seems that your problem is simply a concurrency issue. The post function takes a callback argument to tell you when the post has been finished. You cannot make the alert in global scope like this and expect that the post has already been finished. You have to move it to the callback function.

Answer (score 4):

The reason your code fails is because `post()` will start an [asynchronous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_synchronization) request to the server. What that means for you is that `post()` returns immediately, **not** after the request completes, like you are expecting.

What you need, then, is for the request to be synchronous and block the current thread until the request completes. Thus,

```
var it_works = false;

$.ajax({
  url: 'some_file.php',
  async: false,  # makes request synchronous
  success: function() {
    it_works = true;
  }
});

alert(it_works);
```