# Global access to array values made from Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, getjson

```
$.getJSON("sluzba.json", function(result){
    array = $.each(result, function(value){
        return value;
    });
  tableMaker(array);
});
```

This is my code, I want to have an access to the array from outside the scope of this function.

Is it possible?

Please help...

Comment: Use a Promise: https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Global variables after Ajax requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222347/javascript-global-variables-after-ajax-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can using a `callback` method.

```
function myFunction(callback){
    $.getJSON("sluzba.json", function(result){
    array = $.each(result, function(value){
       return value;
    });
    callback(array);
    tableMaker(array);
    });
}
myFunction(function(myArray){
   console.log(myArray);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, callback helped! I've tried it before, but put it in wrong place

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to just use a global variable.

```
var array;
$.getJSON("sluzba.json", function(result){
    array = $.each(result, function(value){
        return value;
    });
  tableMaker(array);
});
```